# Read from file a selected range of lines and store into arrays

Tags: c++

I have a data file like this

```
               1.2   0.07  0.3
               2.3   1.0    1.1
               0.3   2.2    1.1

               12.2  0.0   0.0                   
               0.0   20.1   0.0
               1.2   0.07  0.3
               2.3   1.0    1.1
               0.3   2.2    1.1
```

I need to read the file and store the first 3 lines into a matrix

```
                  1.2   0.07  0.3
           A =    2.3   1.0    1.1
                  0.3   2.2    1.1
```

and from line 4 to the end into another matrix

```
                  12.2  0.0   0.0                   
                  0.0   20.1   0.0
           B =    1.2   0.07  0.3
                  2.3   1.0    1.1
                  0.3   2.2    1.1
```

up to now I was only able to create the first matrix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>    
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const char * filename = "data.txt";
ifstream is(filename);
if (!is)
{
    cout << "Unable to open file: " << filename << endl;
    return 1;
}

int height = 3, width = 3;

// Dynamic array
double *vec;
vec = new double*[height];
for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
   vec[i] = new double[width];

// Read the data
for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
    for (int j=0; j< width; j++)
        is >> vec[i][j];
if (!is)
    cout << "Error reading into array" << endl;

// Display the data
for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j< width; j++)
        cout << setw(5) << vec[i][j];
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "done" << endl;

// Delete the array
for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
    delete [] vec[i];
delete    [] vec;

return 0;
}
```

Then  how do I skip to line 5 to create matrix B? 
I'd like to have something like a loop (from 0 to 3 for matrix A and from 4 to 8 for matrix B)

Please, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, if you need to skip first matrix data when file is just open

```
// Skip the data
double dummy;
for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
    for (int j=0; j< width; j++)
        is >> dummy;
```

(height and width are for skipped matrix A)

if you have to read matrix B right after matrix A, you don't need to skip anything

```
#include <fstream>    
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string filename = "data.txt";
    ifstream is(filename);
    if (!is)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file: " << filename << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int height = 3, width = 3;

    // Dynamic array
    vector<double> A(height * width);

    // Read the data
    for (int i = 0; is && i < height; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            is >> A[i * width + j];
    if (!is)
        cout << "Error reading into array" << endl;

    // Display the data
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            cout << setw(5) << A[i * width + j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Delete the array
    A.clear();

    // reading B
    height = 5;

    // Dynamic array
    vector<double> B(height * width);

    // Read the data
    for (int i = 0; is && i < height; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            is >> B[i * width + j];
    if (!is)
        cout << "Error reading into array" << endl;

    // Display the data
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            cout << setw(5) << B[i * width + j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    B.clear();

    cout << "done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
  1.2 0.07  0.3
  2.3    1  1.1
  0.3  2.2  1.1

 12.2    0    0
    0 20.1    0
  1.2 0.07  0.3
  2.3    1  1.1
  0.3  2.2  1.1

done
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You can do the reading as copy_n(istream_iterator<double>(is), width*height, A.begin()); There's no need for a nested loop and index arithmetic

Comment: @Caleth Completely agreed. Just didn't want to break away from OP's code too far

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your style of code, (which I don't recommend because of the error-prone `new[]`'ing and `delete`'ing), then one way, not the only way, is simply to loop for precisely 2 iterations, one for each of the matrices. The second loop will continue extracting doubles where it left off, and the empty newline will be ignored.

```
int height = 3, width = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
    // Dynamic array ...
    // Read the data ...
    // Display the data ...
    // Delete the array ...

    height = 5;
    }
```

If your next question is what if I don't know there are 5 more lines, but maybe 6, or 10, or 423, then the answer will be don't use `new double[]` but prefer `std::vector`.